# How to make a promise clean up after it has been used

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have an async function that creates a folder and I want to be able to do a computation with this folder and then have the same function remove it.

What I have tried:

```
const t = async () => {
 let createdFolderPath = ''

 return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  createdFolderPath = await createAFolder()
  console.log('Folder Created')
  resolve(createdFolderPath)
 }).finally(async () => {
  await deleteCreatedFolder(createdFolderPath)
  console.log('Deleted Folder')
  })
}

t().then(async (folderpath) => {
  await doSomethingWithFolderThatIsAsync(folderPath)
  console.log('Computation Done')
})
```

What I want to happen is:

```
Folder Created
Computation Done
Deleted Folder
```

What actually happens is:

```
Folder Created
Deleted Folder
Computation Done
```

I want the `t` function to also remove the folder so the person using it doesn't have to worry about removing the folder.

Comment: `async` functions always return a `Promise`. Using the `Promise` constructor seems useless in your code and also avoid mixing promise-chaining with `async-await` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd pass the `.then` callback into `t` instead of using the returned Promise from `t`. You should also avoid the explicit Promise construction antipattern:

```
const t = async (thenCallback) => {
  let createdFolderPath = ''

  return createAFolder()
  .then(thenCallback)
  .finally(async () => {
    await deleteCreatedFolder(createdFolderPath)
    console.log('Deleted Folder')
  })
}

t(async (folderpath) => {
  await doSomethingWithFolderThatIsAsync(folderPath)
  console.log('Computation Done')
})
.then(() => {
  // everything finished
});
```

Comment: This is good, but I am looking to hold onto the normal syntax of `.then` or `await`

Comment: What do you mean? Promises are still being used in the code in the answer, you can use `.then` or `await` wherever desired.

Comment: That's true however I want the cleaning up to happen after the `.then` has finished, not before. I wanna pass the callback inside `.then`

Comment: What you're looking for isn't possible - you can't have a Promise have `.then` called on it *elsewhere* and have the creator of the Promise chain something onto that. You could make `.then` syntax possible if you returned an object with a custom `.then` method, but that'd be a horrible idea. Passing the intermediate function as a callback is the only good approach, I think.

Comment: Why would it be a horrible idea to do that?

Comment: Because then the object that was returned wouldn't be a standard Promise, and using `.then` on something that isn't actually a Promise would be extremely confusing to anyone who reads the code later. Using a *different* name, eg `thenIntermediate`, would make more sense, but just passing the callback alone would make even more sense.